# Run exe file from stored procedure fails while manually it succeeds

Tags: sql-server, security, stored-procedures, batch-file

I use SQL Server 2008.  Currently I'm working on a stored procedure that has needs (among other things) to print a file.

Problem:  The text file I create in the sp needs to be printed as landscape.  I use a program DOSPrinter.exe which is a universel printer driver that adds a file to the (default) printer cue from commandline.

I use xp_cmdshell to do this.  The xp_cmdshell has sufficient rights I guess.  I use it to perform some file copy actions and after I set the security on the used directories it works perfectly.

I gave the DOSPrinter the same rights, together with the print device.

However, when type the command manually (C:\temp\DOSPrinter "C:\temp\test.txt") in a command window, the file appears in the print cue.
When I put the same command in a bat file, and call the bat file manually from a cmd window, the file is send to the print cue.

When I try to place the command in a stored procedure:

```
    SET @bcpCommand = 'C:\temp\DOSPrinter.exe C:\temp\test.txt'
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

the file is not send to the print cue.  If I gtry to call the bat file from the sp, again no file in the print cue.  I'm kinda desperate.

Maybe someone can help me give me some ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks,

jan_solo

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the feature is enabled:

```
exec sp_configure ‘show advanced options’, 1
go
reconfigure
go
exec sp_configure ‘xp_cmdshell’, 1
go
reconfigure
go
```

If it is, can you post the output the command sends you?  What happens if you try to run `dir *.*` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the command in an SSMS window rather than a command window?  I don't think the problem is the stored procedure, per se.  I think the problem is SQL Server accessing the executable and/or file.

Now, a dum question.  Are you running SQL Server on the same machine where you are running SSMS?  If not, the problem is simple.  The command is on your local machine, but it is not on the server machine.

If you are running all on the same machine and you know that xp_cmdshell is working, then the problem gets harder.  It might be a delegation of permissions problem.  It might be that the user that running SQL Server Agent does not have permission to look at the temp file.  Or there might be some other cause.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a weekend to think about it and the answer was actually simpler then I expected...

The point is that the universal printer driver sends the text document to the **default** printer, as I had indicated.  XP_cmdshell executes under a different user then the one I was logged on with.

The only thing I had to do is add a default printer with the XP_cmdshell before printing the file:

```
    SET @bcpCommand = 'rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /q /n "My_Printer"'
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand

    SET @bcpCommand = 'C:\temp\DOSPrinter.exe C:\temp\test.txt'
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

When I run the stored procedure, the file does appear in the print cue.

Everyone, thanks for the answers anyway :-)